# Скрипт перевода условного форматирования в обычный формат

Tags: google-apps-script, google-spreadsheet

Сидел долго ломал голову как записать макрос на перевод всего листа в значение, а после оставление от условного форматирования лишь заливку. Это надо для скачивания файла в excel, с гугла условное форматирование там слетает. Помогите написать скрипт, пожалуйста.
**Этапы:**

1. Выделяется весь лист и вставляется как значение (для удаления
   формул)
2. Выделяется весь лист, удаляется условное форматирование и вставляется обычной заливкой (вставка формата)

Comment: Вопрос сформулирован с нарушениями правил сообщества.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Необходимо передать в эту функцию тот лист, который нужно сбросить

```js
function freezeFormat_(sheet) {
  const range = sheet.getDataRange()
  const backgrounds = range.getBackgrounds();
  const colors = range.getFontColors();
  range.setBackgrounds(backgrounds).setFontColors(colors);
}
```

Чтобы исключить ошибку, можно сначала делать копию листа. В данном случае `Sheet3`

```js
function run() {
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive()
    .getSheetByName('Sheet3')
    .copyTo(SpreadsheetApp.getActive());
  freezeFormat_(sheet);
}
```

Comment: Спасибо! Все заработало